# Traversing tree made from  DefaultMutableTreeNode

Tags: java, swing, parsing, tree

We have a tree structure implemented using the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` specified in Java.

Is there any way of traversing it, that is inbuilt?

If not, please suggest other techniques.

Comment: What do you mean by parsing it?  Typically you would parse an expression to build an internal representation (like the tree structure you already have).  Do you simply want to traverse the tree?

Comment: Sorry for that.Yes I meant traversing it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you mean you want to traverse the tree you can call `breadthFirstEnumeration()` or `depthFirstEnumeration()` in order to iterate over all nodes in the tree.

Example:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = ...

Enumeration en = root.depthFirstEnumeration();
while (en.hasMoreElements()) {

  // Unfortunately the enumeration isn't genericised so we need to downcast
  // when calling nextElement():
  DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) en.nextElement();
}
```

Comment: How do I get access to  each node that returned by the search algorithm? Can you point me to a good resource, please.

Comment: Finally what I needed! I was using an ArrayList that I added nodes to as I created them which was fine, but because I'm using duplicated entries in different folders I needed a new array for each folder and then it gets large fast. Also thanks to the below answer I can process them 2 times as fast!

Answer (score 20):

You have in theory four ways to walk the tree from a node (`DefaultMutableTreeNode`):

- `breadthFirstEnumeration`
- `depthFirstEnumeration`
- `preorderEnumeration`
- `postorderEnumeration`

but actually depth first is implemented as postorder.
The JavaDoc is a bit terse on the differences on these methods. I came here looking for an answer, but I ended by doing the test myself, with a code looking like:

```
  TreeModel model = tree.getModel();

  DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
  // Just changing enumeration kind here
  Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode> en = rootNode.preorderEnumeration();
  while (en.hasMoreElements())
  {
     DefaultMutableTreeNode node = en.nextElement();
     TreeNode[] path = node.getPath();
     System.out.println((node.isLeaf() ? "  - " : "+ ") + path[path.length - 1]);
  }
```

I could have refined with indentation proportional to level, but it was just a quick hack.

So, what are the differences?

- `preorderEnumeration` = from top of tree to bottom, as if you were using the down arrow to walk it
- `postorderEnumeration` = `depthFirstEnumeration` = first list the deepest leafs of the first path, then their parent, then the deepest leafs of the second path, etc.
- `breadthFirstEnumeration` = list the elements at the first level, then the elements at the second level, and so on

To be more concrete:

```
+ Root
  + Folder 1
    - Leaf F1
    - Leaf F1
 + Folder 2
    + Sub-folder 1
      - Leaf SF1
      - Leaf SF1
    + Sub-folder 2
      - Leaf SF2
      - Leaf SF2
```

♦ Preorder: as shown above
♦ DepthFirst/Postorder:
Leaf F1, Leaf F1, Folder 1
Leaf SF1, Leaf SF1, Sub-folder 1
Leaf SF 2, Leaf SF2, Sub-folder 2, Folder 2, Root
♦ BreathFirst:
Root
Folder 1, Folder 2
Leaf F1, Leaf F1, Sub-folder 1, Sub-folder 2
Leaf SF 1, Leaf SF 1, Leaf SF 2, Leaf SF 2

Answer (score 2):

Here's another description of the 3 enumeration Methods, that may be easier to understand.

```
en = root.breadthFirstEnumeration();
//Enumeration lists all nodes at depth 0 (aka root)
//Then all nodes at depth 1 (aka root's children, top to bottom ordering)
//Then all nodes at depth 2, and so on till max depth reached

en = root.preorderEnumeration(); 
//Imagine your JTree is fully expanded (where each node = a row)
//Enumeration will list nodes from top to bottom (regardless of leaf or not)

en = root.postorderEnumeration(); //Equivalent to root.depthFirstEnumeration();
//Imagine a fully expanded copy of your JTree (where each node = a row)
//This will allow you to visualize what Enumeration List will look like
while(treecopy.hasNodes() ) {
list 1st leaf sighted going from top to bottom, then remove that leaf }
//as the leafs are removed, branches then become leafs, and root is last enumerated.
```

Comment: Originally I didn't say what I meant, I meant it as a visualization assist, but I accidentally said it literally. I've changed it now, hopefully it's more clear, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, breadtFirst is inorder. Preorder (First root, then children) is supported as well (preorderEnumeration)